# Why GetKeyState changed the behavior of ToUnicodeEx?

Tags: c++, winapi

In the code below:-

```
BYTE ks[256];
auto keyboard_layout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);
GetKeyboardState(ks);
auto w = WCHAR(malloc(1));
ToUnicodeEx(wParam, MapVirtualKey(wParam, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC), ks, LPWSTR(&w), 1, 0, keyboard_layout);
wcout << "KEY:" << w << endl;
```

The output only shows lowercase letters such as :-

```
KEY:a
KEY:b
KEY:2
```

Even when pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

**But** adding `GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT)` and/or `GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL)` in the code below:-

```
auto shifted = false;
auto caps = false;
if (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0)
{
    shifted = true;
    cout << "Shifted!" << endl;
}
if (GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) < 0)
{
    shifted = true;
    cout << "Caps!" << endl;
}
BYTE ks[256];
auto keyboard_layout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);
GetKeyboardState(ks);
auto w = WCHAR(malloc(1));
ToUnicodeEx(wParam, MapVirtualKey(wParam, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC), ks, LPWSTR(&w), 1, 0, keyboard_layout);
wcout << "KEY:" << w << endl;
```

The behavior of the code changed directly when pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to

```
KEY:A
KEY:B
KEY:@
```

I tried this on `ToUnicode`, `ToAsciiEx` and `ToAscii` and they shows the same situation as above.

I used `WH_KEYBOARD` hook in a separate DLL file called `hook.dll` and linked with a console application.

So my question is: why `GetKeyState` function enabled the detection of <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key? In addition,

Comment: GetKeyState() cannot work reliably in a console mode process.  It returns the *buffered* state of the keyboard, the state it had when the key was pressed.  That updates when the app calls GetMessage(), a console mode app doesn't.  It does update sometimes however, the exact trigger has never been obvious to me.  Consider synthesizing your own keyboard state with GetAsyncKeyState() or do what works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `auto w = WCHAR(malloc(1))` is wrong. `malloc()` dynamically allocates a block of bytes, not characters. `WCHAR` is 2 bytes in size, but you are allocating only 1 byte. Which doesn't matter since you don't use the pointer anyway.  You are type-casting the pointer to a single `WCHAR`, truncating the pointer value. And then you are dismissing the value when passing `&w` to `ToUnicodeEx()` as it will overwrite the value of `w`.  You are then leaking the allocated memory since you are not calling `free()` to deallocate it.

You don't need the `malloc()` at all:

```
WCHAR w;
ToUnicodeEx(..., &w, 1, ...);
wcout << "KEY:" << w << endl;
```

However, `ToUnicodeEx()` can potentially return more than 2 characters, so you should allocate extra room to account for that. Just use a local fixed array, like you do for `GetKeyboardState()`. And do pay attention to the return value, it contains important information.

As for the key states, since you are calling `GetKeyboardState()`, you don't need to use `GetKeyState()`.

Try something more like this:

```
BYTE ks[256];
auto keyboard_layout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);
GetKeyboardState(ks);

if (ks[VK_SHIFT] & 0x80) wcout << L"Shifted!" << endl;
if (ks[VK_CAPITAL] & 0x80) wcout << L"Caps!" << endl;

WCHAR w[5] = {};
int ret = ToUnicodeEx(wParam, MapVirtualKey(wParam, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC), ks, w, 4, 0, keyboard_layout);
switch (ret)
{
case -1:
    wcout << L"DEAD KEY:" << w << endl;
    break;
case 0:
    wcout << L"NO TRANSLATION" << endl;
    break;
case 1:
    wcout << L"KEY:" << w << endl;
    break;
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
    w[ret] = 0;
    wcout << L"KEYS:" << w << endl;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Yo're right about memory leaking and I forgot to change it. But the problem still exists because `GetKeyState` enabled all keyboard input when pressing shift or caps. Even  what ever value you type `GetKeyState(0)`