# Does GetKeyState generate input message?

Tags: c++

```c
const int KEY_0 = 0x30;
void main() {
    byte keyState[256];
    ZeroMemory(keyState, sizeof(byte) * 255);

    byte pressed = (keyState[KEY_0] & 0x80);
    while (pressed == false)
    {
        ZeroMemory(keyState, sizeof(byte) * 255);
        //GetKeyState(0);  // with this line, works well. It makes GetKeyboardState(KEY_0) works.
        //GetAsyncKeyState(KEY_0);
        GetKeyboardState(keyState);
        pressed = (keyState[KEY_0] & 0x80);
    };
}
```

I have learn that this code does not work because `GetKeyboardState()` get values generated after a keyboard message is processed. As no keyboard message is generated, the loop will not stop. That is what I understand.

And [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) says:

> An application calls GetKeyState in response to a keyboard-input message. This function retrieves the state of the key when the input message was generated.

I'm confused, as the upper code with `GetKeyState(0);` works well, which means `GetKeyState()` makes a message about the keyboard?

How can I understand `GetKeyState()` and `GetKeyboardState()`?

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `const` to establish constants like `KEY_0`. Avoid `#define` as it's not properly typed.

Comment: Why the forced `DWORD`?

Comment: I think that is not important in this post but I revised.

Comment: That use of `DWORD` seems entirely unnecessary. A regular `int` will be fine.

Comment: When making post I missed that. I revised.

Comment: Did `GetKeyboardState()` return success?

Comment: Yes. It returns true. Why you asks whether it success?

Comment: It's also worth [reading the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardstate), in particular: "To retrieve status information for an individual key, use the `GetKeyState` function. To retrieve the current state for an individual key regardless of whether the corresponding keyboard message has been retrieved from the message queue, use the `GetAsyncKeyState` function."

Comment: I know that. But What I want to know is how getkeystate works.

Comment: Why are you asking for key `0` instead of your `KEY_0` ID?

Comment: I'm not sure where the confusion here is. `GetAsyncKeyState(KEY_0)` seems like what you want.

Comment: That is not important. As my purpose of GetKeyState() is to make GetKeyboardState works. If you runs the upper code you get eternal loops but with the line GetKeyState() It can break if you press the 0 button.

Comment: Well, yes, this code is designed to utterly thrash the CPU. It doesn't wait for a keypress, it just hammers the polling functions. A better way would be to listen for a keypress message. This is usually done in `WinMain` via the [event loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues) built around `GetMessage()`.

Comment: I read about what you write in other stack overflow post. Then It means GetKeyState makes message about keyboard?

Comment: I mean that this approach of using 100% CPU while waiting for a keypress is not the way you want to handle this. The functions you're using are not intended for this situation. You need to *at least* [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) for short periods of time, like 100ms should be fine, inside of that loop, to avoid excessive CPU use. It's better to listen to incoming Windows messages and filter out those related to keyboard activity. You will be notified the instant any key is pressed.

Comment: No. Even with the line "Sleep(1000)" it does not work. I'd run in my computer.

Comment: @Mona04_ `GetKeyState()` does not generate input messages. The same documentation you linked to also says: "*The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue. **The status does not reflect the interrupt-level state associated with the hardware.** Use the `GetAsyncKeyState` function to retrieve that information.*" However, there are other questions on SO that describe similar results as yours (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719020) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037204/)) but don't explain WHY it happens